# JsonIgnore for Scala method with default parameters does not work as expected

Tags: scala, jackson

I would like to mark the default method generated by scala compiler to be ignored from being serialized.

`@JsonIgnore def getSum(a: Int, b: Int = 2): Int = a + b`

compiler creates two methods:

`def getSum(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a.+(b);`

`<synthetic> def getSum$default$2(): Int = 2; (default value at position 2)`

The first method getSum does not get serialized as the JsonIgnore is applied on it, but the new default parm method generated is serialized by jackson, how to tell Jackson to not serialize it?

Example:

```
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore
  import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

  case class A(id: Int) {
    @JsonIgnore def getSum(a: Int, b: Int = 2): Int = a + b
  }

  @Test
  def test(): Unit = {
    val a = A(5)
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    println(mapper.writeValueAsString(a))
  }
```

output: `{"id":5,"sum$default$2":2}`

Comment: I’m surprised that Jackson tries to serialise a getter with an argument. What is the result? Does it throw an exception?

Comment: it does not throw exception, just that sum$default$2 is one of the keys in serialized json.

Comment: How is that possible if `a` needs to be provided to call the method? Have you tested this with the code in your question or only some other code not shown?  Please edit the question to contain a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including the output it produces.

Comment: Which library defines `SerDeUtils.serializeJson`? If it is custom code, please include it in the question, too.

Comment: I could reproduce the result in Scastie. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/FF5MB7MfTCqPyAWdckopvg Very surprising to me! I'll try to work out an explanation.

Comment: I know why it is happening but I dont know how to fix it.
```def getSum(a: Int, b: Int = 2): Int = a+b``` compiles to
``` def getSum(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a.+(b);   <synthetic> def getSum$default$2(): Int = 2;```
 and jackson thinks getSum$default$2 is a getter for sum$default$2, so let me serialize it

Comment: I understand now. I incorrectly believed that the method generated by  the Scala compiler would forward the method call with the default arguments inlined, but in fact it returns the default value for that parameter. I added an answer with some workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug, but there are workarounds:

## Explicitly ignore the generated property

The `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation can be used at the class level.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(Array("sum$default$2"))
case class A(id: Int) {
  def getSum(a: Int, b: Int = 2): Int = a + b
}
```

## Rename the method

It's detected as a property because it matches the JavaBeans getter convention. If the method name can be changed to remove the `get` prefix, it won't be treated as a property by Jackson:

```
case class A(id: Int) {
  def calculateSum(a: Int, b: Int = 2): Int = a + b
}
```

## Avoid default arguments

Of course, another option is to avoid the use of default arguments entirely in favour of method overloading:

```
case class A(id: Int) {
  def getSum(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
  def getSum(a: Int): Int = getSum(a, 2)
}
```

These examples are all demonstrated in this Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/TimMoore/werEmJF9S7ip4QP5sT73CQ/39

All of these options produce this JSON:

```
{"id":5}
```

Comment: I opened a pull request to ignore these generated methods https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/pull/603

Comment: it's in the 2.14 branch - so it will appear when the 2.14.0 RCs start to appear (soon-ish)

Comment: Glad it helped, @user19953539! If this answers your question satisfactorily, I would appreciate if you mark it as an accepted answer and vote it up. 